# Slotted wing loading and structural analysis

Tags: performance-calculation

I'm trying to determine moments and forces on a wing with a fixed leading edge slot (trying to verify the Ragwing RW19 wing before starting the project). It's quite straightforward for a non-slotted wing, but when working with slots, I've run into several problems I don't know how to solve.

- How do I determine the Cl and Cm of such wing? The XFOIL simulator is not able to work with two element profile AFAIK.
- Should I calculate the wing loading for non-slotted wing only or should I also add the area of the slot?
- Where is the aerodynamic center of the slotted profile? Is it around quarter chord (approximately) from the leading edge of the non-slotted wing or is it measured from the leading edge of the slot?